# GWT Junit - error='no compilation unit for that type was seen'

Tags: gwt, junit

I'm trying to run a GWT unit test in a sample app.  I ran

```
cmd /c /java/gwt-windows-1.6.4/webAppCreator.cmd -out gwttasks com.gwttasks.GwtTasks
```

Copied in junit-4.5.jar into a lib directory, and added that to the classpath.

Ran:

```
cmd /c /java/gwt-windows-1.6.4/junitCreator.cmd -junit lib/junit-4.5.jar -module com.gwttasks.GwtTasks -eclipse GwtTasks com.gwt
tasks.unit.GwtJunit
```

When I try to run any of the generated cmd file (such as GwtJunit-hosted.cmd) or any of the launch files, I get the following error.  All the web pages I've seen say to add the test source to the classpath, but it's already there, so that's not the problem.  Anyone else seen this?

```
com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitFatalLaunchException: The test class 'com.gwttasks.unit.GwtJunit' was not found in module 'com.gwttasks.GwtTasks'; no compilation unit for that type was seen
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.checkTestClassInCurrentModule(JUnitShell.java:390)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:626)
    ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer could be found here :
http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/testing_gwt_applications

Comment: It would be nice to have this answer here on StackOverflow in case the link gets broken:

* To fix this, open the Run Dialog
* Click on the Classpath tab and click on User Entries.
* Click on the Advanced button and select Add Folders.
* In the Folder Selection dialog, select your source and test directories (e.g. src/main/java and src/test/java).

Answer (score 4):

In netbeans I added the src/java and test to the class path and debugging worked!!!!!
THANKS

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add that I had the same problem, because I did the (very silly) mistake to **not** put the GWTTestCase class into the "client" directory, but into another one. No wonder it wasn't found ;)